# WPForms: dotted border is being added to my submit button

Tags: wordpress

I am struggling with a weird occurrence of a dotted border around my submit button in [WPForms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpforms-lite/).

I cannot find it in the CSS when I use inspect element.

I have noticed that if I remove the CSS rule `position: relative` from the button that has the border it jumps around the whole form.

[image: screenshot of the form with the issue]

Comment: You understand that nobody can help you with this question as you have it posted.

Comment: @HowardE tell me how I should post it becouse I don't know

Comment: You need to share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help.